# How to override default login mechanism of Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.6, laravel-authentication

I want the user to login only if **status** field in **users** table is set to **1**. If it is **0** then simply return error stating **user account is not active**.

So after creating the **status field** in the table, where can I make the check that the user'status is 1 then only login otherwise throw error.

I tried to find where the default auth check is made but cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to simply override `credentials()` which is defined in `AuthenticatesUsers.php`. the default login method use `AuthenticatesUsers` trait. so go login controller and overwrite like this.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email'=>$request->{$this->username()},
            'password'=>$request->password,
            'status'=>1

        ];
    }
```

> Note: don't forget to import Request class and don't change anything whatever defined in vendor directory.

Comment: awesome! works perfectly...thnx. One more question, does overriding the credentials method like this cause any security issues ?

Comment: no there is no security  issue  because this is functionality given by trait

Comment: But there is one more problem...even if user's status is 0 if he uses default forgot password mechanism then he gets logged in. should I do the same in ResetPasswordController ?

Comment: Laravel provides the forgot password link in the login page. So if a user whose status is 0 uses the forgot password mechanism for resetting password then he gets logged in after providing new password in reset password form

Comment: Go to your forget password controller and paste it -protected function validateEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $userStatus=User::where('email',$request->email);
        if ($userStatus->YourStatusField==0) {
            return redirect()->back()->with(['message'=>'your account is not active']);
        }
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);
    }

Comment: Please check I have created a new question on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51076276/how-to-override-default-forgot-password-mechanism-of-laravel-5-6

Comment: check my given answer