# How to override default forgot password mechanism of Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6, forgot-password

I wanted to login the user if his status field of users table was set to 1 otherwise not. So this problem was solved in this question which I had asked.

[How to override default login mechanism of Laravel 5.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075201/how-to-override-default-login-mechanism-of-laravel-5-6)

But now I am having another problem. When a user whose status is **0(not active)** clicks the **default forgot password link** in **login page** and enters his email address and then clicks the reset link and fills the new password, **he automatically gets logged in even though his status is 0(not active).**

So how can I prevent the forgot password mechanism if user's status is 0 ?

Comment: Trace the route and find where to forget-password function is being called and from there look for the query that changes the status to 0.

Comment: From the last answer if you remove the 'status'=>1 then it will work as you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to ForgotPasswordController and paste it. the same mechanism exist [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51075201/how-to-override-default-login-mechanism-of-laravel-5-6) . therefor I am not explaining properly.

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);
        $userStatus=User::where('email','=',$request->email)->limit(1)->get();
            if (isset($userStatus)) {
                if ($userStatus[0]->role==0) {
                return redirect()->back()->with(['massage'=>'Please activate account first']);
            }
        }


        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Comment: I think there is a need to include if(isset($userStatus)) before if($userStatus[0]->role==0) as it may throw error if no such user with that email is present

Comment: There is no need anything

Comment: You can change role with status or whatever you want

Comment: Trying to get property 'status' of non-object error is generating as $userStatus can be null if some random email is provided so just include isset($userStatus) so I can accept your answer

Comment: you are right actually I did not test it. now I updated the answer with isset()